# can not open input file libpng15-vc9.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, zlib, gdal, libpng

I am setting up my GDAL 1.8.0 Project in Visual Studio 2010 Windows, I am on way to add libpng to project.

My libpng release libs are under following folder... They are successfully built with zlib in this folder, as you can see there are no files missing as per VTP site.

> D:\libpng-16

[image: libpng files image]

And I have also changed additional libraries file names.

[image: files]

Even though I added path in Property Manager, this error is still coming.

[image: added folder path image]

Still I am getting following error

[image: error]

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should give absolute path d:/libpng-16/libpng16.lib

or

Add the path (d:/libpng-16) in Linker->General->Additional Library Directives

The same applies for all the other libraries also.

Comment: All other libraries are working.... only libpng is having the problem... see the snapshot for linker

Comment: I will let you know with absolut path as I am not in office right now.. Thank You..