# ImageMagick with C++ and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, imagemagick

I can't add ImageMagick++ library to my VS2012 project. I saw the same topics, but they didn't help me. I added links to "Additional Library Directories" and to "Additional Dependencies" but I still have some errors. I have done the same procedure before, but this time something is wrong.
 [image]
[image]
[image]

Please, advise me something!

Comment: Maybe post a screen-grab of your linker/library settings...

Comment: Do you have `Magick++-config` tool for windows?

Comment: @SHR, Hm, no. What is it? I just downloaded ImageMagick, installed it and added links to `lib` and `include` folders.

Comment: Have you added the library to the linker's input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this post of adding the static libraries. Same should apply for you also.
[static libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525693/can-not-open-input-file-libpng15-vc9-lib/27527413#27527413)